# Scratch Orgs - Object Limits

Tags: salesforcedx

I have this org which I am trying to leverage SFDX with

They have upped the limits of number of fields on Accounts from 500 to 500+.

Is there anyway to replicate this within a scratch org

Comment: Because scratch orgs are temporary in nature, I would think that Salesforce will not really provide any support around any feature activation or so in scratch orgs (though not really sure about this). You may like to spin off a new scratch org and try pushing all the fields to see if it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this answer, it is not possible in a normal org. However, the [Org Shape](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm) feature may be able to accommodate you (but I cannot confirm this yet, as I don't have enough details on it). If you're interested, you might want to talk to your Account Executive or Customer Success Manager. We're having similar struggles, as our org is a Performance org, and we can't replicate our full source code because of this.